# SBT with Spark-Core 3.0.1 Exception NoClassDefFound for org/apache/log4j/Logger

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, log4j

I am using `Log4j` with `Scala 2.12.12` and `Spark-Core 3.0.1` but when I change the library dependencies to not package spark-core in the fat jar I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at com.some.package.name.Utils$.setup(Utils.scala:207)
    at com.some.package.name.Main$.main(Main.scala:9)
    at com.some.package.name.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

The compilation is successful and if I remove the `provided` clause from the dependencies line everything works fine. My `build.sbt` is as follows:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.1" % "provided",
"org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.13.3",
"org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.13.3",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0" % "test",
"com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "3.0.1_1.0.0" % Test)
```

If I remove my code which writes to the logger the setup for `SparkContext` is indicated as the line from which the error originates.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem when trying to run my application on EMR 6.2.

I have found a [comment on qubole github project](https://github.com/qubole/s3-sqs-connector/issues/6) claiming AWS' spark-core JAR is missing org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class, but I have no way to verify if this is true.

Comment: I accept this as a partial answer, contributing something to the answering process for this problem, while there is no full answer yet. Note however, that this interpretation might not be shared by other users. Maybe you can get a little closer to [answer].